# format of stored session parameters in windows differs from linux in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, session-variables

I'm developing a project with a friend. I'm working on Windows and he is on Linux. We both work locally and commit the work done to a Linux server.

When I try to use stored session parameters, I have an error like

```
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

The output of the parameter in my local is like:

```
{u'marinaId': [u'2'], u'workingHour': [u''], u'barter': [u'0'], u'height': [u''], u'year': [u''] ...
```

and in my friend's local:

```
{u'marinaId': u'2', u'workingHour': u'', u'barter': u'0', u'height': u'', u'year': u'' ...
```

Parameters are posted from a page, saved to session and sent to another function as below:

```
def new_classified_2(request):
    ...
    request.session['step2'] = request.POST
    ...

def new_classified_3(request):
    ...
    step2 = request.session['step2']
    print step2
    ...
```

Do you have any idea why we have this difference?